# How can I find the function name while navigating code?

Tags: navigation

I use Ctags and vim to browse by C source code. Quite often than not I am in middle of a long function and want to quickly check the name of the function that the browsing. I use the "{" to jump to the start of the function that I am in and `''` to jump back to location in the function that I came from.

Is there any easier way of doing this? Maybe there is a plugin that shows the function that we are currently in.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is to find the first unindented line that starts with a letter (by the way, this is exactly what `diff -p` does).

I'm sure I borrowed this trick somewhere, but I can't remember the origin. Anyway, here it is:

```
" '\p' to show what function we are in (like 'diff -p')
nmap <leader>p <cmd>echo getline(search('^[[:alpha:]$_]', 'bcnW'))<CR>
```

Of course, this is neither perfect nor accurate yet often it works right.

Comment: I wrote a [little plugin](https://github.com/arp242/jumpy.vim) a few years ago which adds mappings for `[[` and `]]` for a bunch of filetypes; I added this as a fallback if a filetype doesn't have a pattern defined, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a plugin, [context.vim](https://github.com/wellle/context.vim) pins current function definition on the first line of the window. (Thanks @Vivian De Smedt, I couldn't find the link myself).

Another suggestion would be something like [tagbar](https://github.com/preservim/tagbar), which displays the code structure in a panel.

If you use [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline), and tagbar together, you can show the current function in the statusline with:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tagbar#enabled = 1
```